# Is it haram to accidentally make an oath to my husband that I did not do something I actually did?

Tags: halal-haram, oaths

I accidentally made an oath to my husband. I told him 'I swear to you, I didn't do it' (even though I had done it) without even thinking twice. I want to undo this. I have heard that swearing on someone is forbidden. I need help to undo this act.

Answer (score 1):

Hoping this will help as additional insight into what you swore about as I have no details and would not like to know.

From an [IslamWeb fatwa](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=82288):

> Whoever takes a false oath commits a grave sin. To make a false oath means to swear to a lie to prove or deny something. ...
>
> As for the expiation of a false oath the Muslim Scholars have two different opinions:
>
> 1. Majority of the Muslim Scholars say that there is no expiation for such an oath since it is greater than any expiation. ...
> 2. One should pay the expiation stated in the Saying of Allah in Qur'an {Allah will not punish you for what is unintentional in your oaths, but He will punish you for your deliberate oaths; for its expiation (a deliberate oath) feed ten Masakin (poor persons), on a scale of the average of that with which you feed your own families; or clothe them; or manumit a slave. But whosoever cannot afford (that), then he should fast for three days. That is the expiation for the oaths when you have sworn. And protect your oaths (i.e. do not swear much). Thus Allah makes clear to you His Ayat (proofs, evidences, verses, lessons, signs, revelations, etc.) that you may be grateful.} [[5:89]](https://quran.com/5:89). These scholars believe that the person who swears deliberately while he is lying has to expiate for his oath, then the one who does a false oath has also to expiate for it in the same way.

In general, I think giving out charity is a good way of expatiation, besides seeking Allah's forgiveness constantly.

Comment: do not you suggest her to say truth?

Answer (score 1):

False oath is a grave sin. You should tell the truth to your husband and repent to Allah for your sins. You can't undo what you did but you can ask for repentance and prevent yourself from doing it again. This is the view of the majority of the Muslim scholars. See [this fatawa](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=82288) for more information.